# Unable to launch twitter api in my iOS program, error with Fabric

Tags: ios, twitter, twitter-fabric

I recently tried to implement twitter login with my app, using Fabric.
While following their tutorial, I made a little change - instead of defining the `TWTRLogInButton` in my .m file, I defined it in my .h file first.

So in my .h file, I set the button like:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet TWTRLogInButton *twitterButton;
```

And in my .m file the code is:

```
_twitterButton = [TWTRLogInButton buttonWithLogInCompletion:^(TWTRSession *session, NSError *error) {
    if (session) {
        NSLog(@"signed in as %@", [session userName]);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}];
```

And it gives me an error like this:

> "[Fabric] Unable to locate application icon"

And ever since I can't find a way to solve this.
I have tried changing the code exactly just as tutorial said as well, but it did not work either. I simply don't understand why Fabric is unable to locate my icon...

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Been forgot about this. Now I completely removed all Twitter APIs, and I plan to reinstall it again once Im done with other stuff. Will update the progress when I have more news.